# Bring out color differences in a material (cycles and node editor)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm currently working on a tree model and I'm trying to reproduce the texture of the bark with the note editor. But it stills not very realistic.
I think that it could be better if I bring out color differences. You know, between two different colors, I want to put a third one. How can I do this ?

**Without bring out (for example)**
[image: Without bring out (for example)]
**With bring out (for example)**
A third color is added at the intersection of the other two.
[image: With bring out (for example)]
**My current nodes**
[image: Current node editor]
**My current material**
[image]